# Windows 7: Wake on LAN (WOL) stopped working

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan

Up until yesterday morning WOL was working on my Windows 7 machine. It has been doing so for about 5 years now, without any problems.

When I wanted to turn on the machine remotely yesterday in the afternoon and today in the morning, it just wouldn't respond to WOL packets.

The driver (Realtek) has these options set (I have changed nothing)

- check: Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power
- check: Allow this device to wake the computer
- check:  only allow a magic packet to wake the computer

In advanced:

- Wake on Magic Packet: Enabled
- Wake on pattern match: Enabled
- Wake-On-Lan Capabilities: Pattern Match & Magic Packet
- WOL & Shutdown Link Speed: 10 Mbps First

When the computer is off, the NIC LEDs are on and blinking

Only a "Definition Update for Microsoft Security Essentials" got installed yessterday.

No software got installed yesterday.

I checked the BIOS, nothing has changed there. There's a setting which allows PCI(x) devices to wake the machine, which is enabled, and this setting has been the one which allowed me to use WOL initially, as it won't shut down the on-board NIC. To test I enabled a Wake-On-Ring, but that didn't help, I think it's a setting for old Modems or something like that. So: BIOS is OK.

What can be causing this?

I did turn off SMBv1 yesterday on the Vista machine which sends the Magic Packet, but I doubt that this could cause the problem. Will try sending it from another device, also will try a Intel PCI NIC-Card I have somewhere.

---

Ok, I can turn the computer on with an Android app on the smartphone, so this is definitely something with the sending machine. Maybe it's the SMBv1-thing, but I guess I just will move the WOL-Triggering over to another machine.

Comment: To wake the computer from an "off" state, wake-on-LAN needs to be configured in the BIOS/UEFI settings as well... did you check those? Maybe a BIOS update or a reset butchered your settings?

Comment: Thanks, that was a good hint, but it's not causing the problem; the BIOS is unchanged.

Comment: Turns out it is the sending machine, the one which sends the packet. Oh, yes, I disabled a ton of services over there yesterday. Maybe one was "important"